# Validating radio input in jQuery on button function

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a radio input with 2 options, to let user define their gender. After clicking the button jquery should check if anything is selected, and,

**if it is** - hide the div with the radio input and show the other one;

**if it`s not** (nothing is selected) show the error text.

Problem is, the code does show error text if nothing is selected, but it does not hide this div and show another one even if the user HAD selected the gender.

**The jQuery part:**

```
           $('#button_1').click(function(){
        gender = $('input:radio[name=1_gender]:checked').val();
              if ('input:radio[name=1_gender].not(:checked') {
              $("label#1_gender_error").show();
              $("input#1_gender").focus();
              return false;
              } 
            if ('input:radio[name=1_gender]:checked') {
            $('#gender_div').hide();
            $('#other_div').show();
            }
          });
```

**The HTML part:**

```
      <div id="gender_div">
    <form name="form_gender" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="gender" id="1_gender_label">You are...</label><br />
      <input type="radio" name="1_gender" id="1_men"  value="men" class="text-input" />
      <label for="men">Men</label><br />

   <input type="radio" name="1_gender" id="1_woman"  value="woman" class="text-input" />
   <label for="woman">Woman</label>
    <br />

    <label class="error" for="1_gender" id="1_gender_error">Text for shaming for not selecting gender</label>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="submit" class="button" id="button_1" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
   $('#button_1').click(function () {


      if (!$("input:radio[name=1_gender]").is(":checked")) {
          $("label#1_gender_error").show();
          $("input#1_gender").focus();
          console.log("not checked")
          return false;
      } else {
          if ('input:radio[name=1_gender]:checked') $('#gender_div').hide();
          $('#other_div').show();
          console.log("checked")
      }
  });
```

Will work for you

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tEwK/)

You're validating a string in your if statement

```
if ('input:radio[name=1_gender].not(:checked')
```

And it will always result to **true**

Comment: Ok you're testing a string inside you if statement that will always result in a true value, using is(":checked") we identify if the radiobuttons are checked since the block of code was the (not checked) desired code i added a ! to negate the value